# Flick/swipe more than just images with jQTouch photo gallery extension

Tags: jquery, touch, gallery, jqtouch, swipe

The [jQTouch photo gallery extension](http://samshull.blogspot.com/2010/06/jqtouch-photo-gallery.html) ([demo](http://samshull.com/jqtouch-r148/demos/main/)) is fantastic, but it only works for images (`<img>`s). I would like to have the same flicking/swiping effect with multiple "page" (`<div>`s).

Has anyone tried to tweak this extension to make it more general, so it works with more than just images? Or, is there any other library (e.g. jQuery plugins) that does what I want or similar?

Comment: At least for me that demo didn't work, everything looked funky. i'm using FF 3.6.9

Comment: You need to use Safari, or at least a WebKit browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-snaps-to-version-3-6)
 may be of help to you... check out the demos and screencasts linked from that page

Comment: you should have included the actual demo link at your original post... it is actually useful: http://bit.ly/bYwb03